# I need to make a subtotal field based off of two fields

Tags: sql

I have two tables `Qut1` and `Qut10`.

`Qut1` has a list of the quotes line items

```
Id LineNum Price
1  0       10
1  1       20
1  2       100
```

`Qut10` has the lines where the subtotal should occur

```
Id AfterLineNum
1  1
1  2
```

Anyone have a idea how I could create script that would give me the Line numbers that need to be added together to get a subtotal?

ie (1, 1.1 (I.e. to be placed after qut1 line 1 but before line 2), 30
(1, 2.1, 100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a query that maps each line item to its corresponding subtotal. It `JOIN`s both tables and uses a correlated subquery with a `NOT EXIST` condition to ensure that the relevant subtotal record is picked.

```
SELECT
  t1.LineNum,
  t1.Price,
  t2.AfterLineNum
FROM
    Qut1 t1
    INNER JOIN Qut10 t2 
        ON t2.AfterLineNum >= t1.LineNum
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM Qut10 
            WHERE AfterLineNum >= LineNum AND AfterLineNum < t2.AfterLineNum
        )
ORDER BY
    t2.AfterLineNum ,
    t1.LineNum
```

You did not tag your RDBMS, but this is standard SQL that should work on most platforms.

**[This DB Fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jiMpBDAyK2HvLvM9rX2EgN/0)** with your sample data yields :

```
| LineNum | Price | AfterLineNum |
| ------- | ----- | ------------ |
| 0       | 10    | 1            |
| 1       | 20    | 1            |
| 2       | 100   | 2            |
```

---

If you are looking to actually compute the subtotals, you can just turn on *aggregation* :

```
SELECT
  t2.AfterLineNum,
  SUM(t1.Price) subtotal
FROM
    Qut1 t1
    INNER JOIN Qut10 t2 
        ON t2.AfterLineNum >= t1.LineNum
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM Qut10 
            WHERE AfterLineNum >= LineNum AND AfterLineNum < t2.AfterLineNum
        )
GROUP BY t2.AfterLineNum
ORDER BY t2.AfterLineNum
```

**[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jiMpBDAyK2HvLvM9rX2EgN/1)** :

```
| AfterLineNum | subtotal |
| ------------ | -------- |
| 1            | 30       |
| 2            | 100      |
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the working version

```
SELECT
  t1."LineNum",
  t1."Price",
  t2."AftLineNum"
FROM
    Qut1 t1
    INNER JOIN Qut10 t2 
        ON ( t2."AftLineNum" >= t1."LineNum" -1
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM Qut10 T00
            WHERE T00."AftLineNum" >= T1."LineNum" -1 AND T00."AftLineNum" < t2."AftLineNum" AND T00."DocEntry" = T1."DocEntry"
        )
        AND T1."DocEntry" = T2."DocEntry" )
WHERE T1."DocEntry" = 49036
ORDER BY
    t2."AftLineNum" ,
    t1."LineNum"
```

Comment: It maybe a "working version" (I did not test/verify!), but explanation is missing. 